# Based on value of first row and first column get label value

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement

I have grid structure of 11 x 10. Example of the structure is as follow.

[image]

Each cell correspond to a particular value based on the value of row and column.
These row and column values are conditions. Such if value is 'a' and '3' return label in cell a3.
I want to create and store data in this structure in python and my grid will be 11 x 10 and the labels of cell can change over time. What is the best way to do this in python?
Which is easy to update and works efficiently as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two arrays for the column and row names. Then you you create a dictionary for the grid and you iterate over the arrays to build your grid.

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
b = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11']

grid = {}

for i in a:
    grid[i] = {}
    for j in b:
        grid[i][j] = i + j

print(grid)
```